# Fiind rows that match multiple criteria in a separate lookup table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm 95% done with a small script that returns a random sample of records using input box criteria matched against 4 or 5 columns. I'd like include rows that the cell value matches one of 40 or 50 different values in separate named range in another spreadsheet. 
At present, I'm filtering: between a date range (based on input boxes), line of business (based on input boxes), only records that are "approved" (no input box, just explicitly stated). 
I can't figure out how to match rows that meet dozens of criteria that might change over time - I'd like to change the lookup table instead of manually entering every single lookup possibility in my code.

I've already tried (Data(i, 13).Value = range("AllBands").value and many variations "like", "in", etc.

**Question: How can I further filter my random selection by matching cell values in column 13 with those that are in a named range in another workbook (called "AllBands") that lists out 40 or 50 acceptable values?**

////

```
Static StartDate As String, LOBName As String, BandName As String, Status As String
  Static EndDate As String

  Dim sDate As Date
  Dim eDate As Date
  Dim Data, Possible, This
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim Ws As Worksheet
  Static Amount As Long
  Dim SheetName As String

  'Get the start date of the range you need
  Do
    StartDate = InputBox("Enter START date (Format as MM/DD/YYYY)", "Generate Random Sample", StartDate)
    If StartDate = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsDate(StartDate) Then Beep
  Loop Until IsDate(StartDate)

  'Get the END date of the range you need
  Do
    EndDate = InputBox("Enter END date (Format as MM/DD/YYYY)", "Generate Random Sample", EndDate)
    If EndDate = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsDate(EndDate) Then Beep
  Loop Until IsDate(EndDate)

  sDate = StartDate
  eDate = EndDate

  LOBName = InputBox("Enter LOB you want sampled (SHP, CC, Etc)", "Generate Random Sample", LOBName)
  If LOBName = "" Then Exit Sub
  If Amount = 0 Then
    Amount = 5 'Default
  Else
    Amount = Amount + 1 'Adjust from last call (see code below)
  End If
  Amount = Application.InputBox("Enter amount (Total number of rows / records you want to return - up to the total number available for date and name parameter)", "Generate Random Sample", Amount, Type:=1)
  If Amount <= 0 Then Exit Sub

  'Read in all data
  Data = Sheets("Reports").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
  'Initialize
  Amount = Amount - 1
  Possible = Array()
  j = -1
  'Collect all row numbers that are possible
  For i = 2 To UBound(Data)
    'Checks in Column 9 for date, checks in column 6 for the LOB that you enter
    If (Data(i, 9) >= sDate) And (Data(i, 9) <= eDate + 1) And (Data(i, 6) = LOBName And _
    (Data(i, 8) = "Approved-PCSP") And (Data(i, 13).Value Like worksheets("LookupFile.xls").range("AllBands"))) _
    Then
      j = j + 1
      ReDim Preserve Possible(0 To j)
      Possible(j) = i
    End If
  Next
////
```

There's a bunch more after this, but it all works for me - wanted to keep this as small as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you're looking to see if array element `Data(i, 13)` exists in the range `AllBands`.

Maybe you could change this bit:

```
And (Data(i, 13).Value Like worksheets("LookupFile.xls").range("AllBands"))
```

to the below (if `AllBands` is a single row or column):

```
And IsNumber(Application.Match(Data(i, 13).Value,Worksheets("LookupFile.xls").Range("AllBands"), 0))
```

or the below (if `AllBands` consists of multiple columns or multiple rows):

```
And Not (Worksheets("LookupFile.xls").Range("AllBands").Find(Data(i, 13), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False) Is Nothing)
```

However, VBA does not offer short-circuit evaluation. So it will always evaluate every boolean expression in the chain/series. It might be better to break the statement up (so you're not needlessly checking `AllBands`, for example, if you already know the date is outside of the date range).

This would mean something like:

```
' Some code here...
If (Data(i, 9) >= sDate) And (Data(i, 9) <= EDate + 1) Then
    If Data(i, 6) = LOBName And (Data(i, 8) = "Approved-PCSP") Then
        If IsNumber(Application.Match(Data(i, 13).Value, Worksheets("LookupFile.xls").Range("AllBands"), 0)) Then
            ' Some code here...
        End If
    End If
End If
' Some code here...
```

It might also be good to store `AllBands` in a variable before the loop (e.g. `Dim cellsToSearch as range`, then `Set cellsToSearch = Worksheets("LookupFile.xls").Range("AllBands")`, then refer to `cellsToSearch` inside the loop.

If the above works okay for you, then good. Probably no need to optimise further.

---

Both of the above approaches will perform a linear search (looping through each value in `AllBands`). On top of that, this linear search will happen for each row you have in the array `Data`.

If the code is taking too long to run, maybe you could sort the data in `AllBands` to allow for a binary search (binary searches can be done via `Application.Vlookup` or `Application.Match` with correct arguments unless I'm mistaken).

Or it may be necessary to use an approach with lower algorithmic complexity e.g. `dictionary`, `collection` (although it offers no `contains` or `exists` function), or any object that internally uses a hash table. So before the loop, you'd add all the values in `AllBands` to a dictionary (watch out for case sensitivity), for example, and then inside the loop you could check (far more quickly) if `Data(i, 13)` matches anything in `AllBands`.

Comment: The first solution worked wonderfully. All of the AllBand data is in one column. Really appreciate the thoughtful and well-described solution.